# Storing OAuth2 client_id and client_secret securely in a client side app

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0

Are there any clever solutions for storing `client_id` and `client_secret` securely in a client side app?

This could be an Android/iOS app that get decompiled.  Or a Chrome Extension that has it in plain text.

If these get compromised the attacker and impersonate your app, piggy backing on it's reputation to encourage the user to authorize access, right?

Curious what solutions exists here.  Thanks!

Comment: What does "piggy backing on it's reputation to encourage the user to authorize access" mean?

Answer (score 3):

For mobile apps, the "authorization code grant" scenario is not recommended because storing the client_secret in a mobile app is not safe. This is why the standard makes a difference between confidential and public clients (see section [2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1)).

You should use the "implicit grant" scenario instead (created for javascript and embedded apps). It does not contain a client_secret because the client couldn't protect it properly anyway, the client uses only its client_id. Since mobile clients are considered potentially unsecure, the server must not issue a refresh token, only a short-living access token.